# use text from textField for naming - maya python

Tags: python, maya

I want to use the output of a textField to serve as a name for a newly created blenshape. However when I press the button to create my shape it only consideres the text that has been defined by me as a stock text that should be replaced. It doesn't consider new letters typed in the box :

```
def buildUI(self, *args):

   self.widgets["bs"] = cmds.textField (tx= "Replace me", editable= True, )

   self.widgets["blendshape_name"] = cmds.textField(self.widgets['bs'],  q=True, text=True)

   cmds.button(label="Create BlendShape ", w=295, h=30, al="center", c=self.blendShape)

def blendShape (self, *args):

   cmds.blendShape ( cmds.ls(sl=True)[1], cmds.ls(sl=True)[0],frontOfChain=True, n= self.widgets["blendshape_name"] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query the blendshape_name only when you run *buildUI* function. You have to read the textfield at every click. So query the blendshape_name inside the function blendShape:

```
def blendShape(self, *args):

    blendshape_name = cmds.textField(self.widgets['bs'],  q=True, text=True)
    cmds.blendShape(cmds.ls(sl=True)[1], cmds.ls(sl=True)[0], frontOfChain=True, n=blendshape_name)
```